# Bootloader for MCU

Tags: microcontroller, bootloader

1. Is bootloader a must and should be required for flashing a program
   hexcode into MCU?
2. If yes, how would a factory fresh MCU be loaded with a
   bootloader hexcode? Is it simply a memory write operation?

Comment: 1) Depends what you mean by "bootloader". An MCU needs to have some very basic functionality to be able to know how to start fetching and executing the actual program code. On top of it it might or might not have another bootloader stage. 2) The (1) thing is usually "burned"/fused into the MCU internal ROM in the factory using their manufacturing process.

Comment: Thanks for response. Bootloader I mean mechanism of fetching program code. Is it something hardwired?

Comment: On the lowest level it is hardwired. But on top of it, as said, there might be a ROM fused L0 bootloader which is performing some very basic initializations and is capable of fetching the actual program or L1 bootloader code from the flash or other storage device.

Answer (score 2):

bootloaders are not required.  But you will eventually need some firmware in your product whether it is a "bootloader" plus an "application" or if it is just an application alone.

And how you program a virgin part and/or reprogram a part once assembled but before delivery if there is a need to do that is half the mcu and half the board.   Each MCU vendor and usually within a family or subset of their array of products they have different solutions for programming the flash/rom in the MCU.  Some require special fixtures with higher voltage that you are not normally going to integrate into your board level product, so these need to be pre-programmed before assembly and likely never field upgradeable (the good old days when we wrote good code using primitive languages).

Most have some sort of interface that can be done in system/circuit.  Some are so limited on pins though, say an 8 pin part, that you may not have enough pins to easily provide in system programming options as well as using those pins as part of the design of the product.  Although some ICT fixtures and associated pcb designs you can sometimes solve that.

Some have a factory installed/burned bootloader allowing for more ISP options, uart, sometimes usb, spi, i2c, etc.  Depends on the vendor and the family and the product.  And this gives you more choices for your pcb design as to what interface you want to use in your mfg fixture and possibly in the field.

And then there are roll your own bootloader options which you have to solve the program the part with the bootloader the first time issue, but after that if you dont mess up the bootloader that is installed you can then use interfaces (ideally in the field not so much in production) that the bootloader enables.  I have a product that we do this way, not so much because we cant get at the device, but to avoid cabling up the product in manufacturing and adding extra time per product at some production level we preprogram the parts and in the case of the processor the pre-programmed item is such that we can upgrade it to the current without additional cabling during production.

Bootloaders are useful as part of the product and user's experience too.  In some cases you want a bootloader (think arduino products) that enables the user to not require special tools or cables or other such features to use the product...

Comment: Hi @old_timer, I keep running into your answers. Would you happen to have some example of bootloader somewhere in a blog or github? I am trying learn more on the topic (overwhelming experience so far). I am reading as much as I can find on stm32 custom bootloader and would be really grateful with some full, yet as simple as possible, example which involves linker script, startup / interrupt handler, vector table, etc.

Comment: my approach is generally a simple srec https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format) decoder using S3 entries (gnu objcopy can do this).  avoid interrupts unless absolutely necessary (not necessary here). you can then load a program into ram and do whatever you want.  have the one you download write to flash or be a more complicated bootloader, etc.  30-50 lines of code if that.

Comment: less is more you want your bootloader to be as bug free as possible, every line of code adds risk, the more complicated the less likely it is going to work the way you want in desperation...

Answer (score 1):

1. No a bootloader is not a requirement.  All MCUs that I am familiar with will start running code stored in the flash memory on power up.  Storing that code does not require a bootloader per-se.  A programmer/flasher can use whatever protocol the specific chip requires in lieu of a bootloader.
2. Using a vendor or 3rd party supplied tool that programs the device.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, a bootloader is not a must.
2. Not applicable as answer to question 1 was a "No".